# How can I view the progress of updates of windows 8 store apps?

Tags: windows-8

I have about 10 updates pending for several updates, but whenever the Store app says that the update process has begun, it takes a really long time, and I have no way of telling if the updates have crashed from trying to update several apps at the same time, or it just takes a long time because a lot of data is being downloaded. Can I see how much MB are downloaded and at which rate?

Comment: The Task Manager shows you what bandwidth is being used per app. Try looking at that.

Comment: You can monitor total size of `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution`. This folder [is](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-files/is-it-safe-to-delete-files-under/8d98d924-b0b1-4f2b-bb4b-13f38126c588) where automatic updates are stored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you open up the Store app and click on updates in the corner it will tell you which ones are pending and installing. I don't think Microsoft put in the feature of seeing how fast each update is and how big each one is as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Windows 8 on a computer, go to the desktop view, open my computer and type in "Control Panel" in the navigation bar. From there you should be familiar with what you're looking at.

Typing in, "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Update" brought me to the old Windows Update that I am familiar with. I couldn't type this in anywhere on the Metro theme part of Windows 8 and the Windows 8 Update "app" just showed me a progress bar with no text or anything...

I'm going through the same "re-learning pains" that you are.

Answer (score 0):

Right click "Start" in Desktop view, select "System", Click on "Windows Update" in the resulting window and you get the familiar progress bar for "Installing update X of Y".  No overall progress, but that wasn't really much use for guessing how long was left anyway as some take much longer than others.